# A public action method 'X' was not found on controller 'Y'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I know this might be easy question with easy answers but I have tried all most all solution and it's not working.

I have an actionlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Sales List", "AllSales", "ROI", new { result_Type = "All" })
```

But when I click on it changes ROI controller to HomeController and gives following error:

```
 A public action method 'AllSales' was not found on controller
 'ROI.Controllers.HomeController'.
```

I dont't know what's the problem. My action metghod `AllSales` is as follow:

```
public ActionResult AllSales(string result_Type)
{
  ViewData["result_Type"] = result_Type;
  return View();            
}
```

and "AllSales" view is rendering partialview like below:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AllSales";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_SelectAllSales", new { result_Type = 
           ViewData["result_Type"].ToString() });}
```

Help me I don't know what is the issue. 
Note: If I render "AllSales" view without any parameter, it is working fine.

Comment: Maybe by accident and not the reason: in the action link you type `resultType` whereas in the method, the parameter name is `result_Type`.

Comment: @Markus That's not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the [`ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) helper correctly. There is not overloaded version of `ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object)`. There is however a `ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, Object, Object)` version which gets matched to your call. The first `Object` parameter is where your set your controller name but is interpreted as a route value(s) object. Therefore, the engine redirects to the `Home` controller.

Use this instead:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Sales List", "AllSales", "ROI", new { result_Type = "All" }, null)
```

This will match the [`ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and will let you specify the controller also.

Comment: Gr8. It is working. I thought the last parameter is optional.

Comment: @DKS, there's no such thing :). Since this member is overloaded, the number and type of the parameters play a very important part. Luckily you can pass along `null` and tell Razor you don't need that parameter.